# Where is \n located in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

I have a have a String which came from a text area: (with the variable name `string`)

```
This is the first line
And this is the second
```

If I were to split that into separate words using `string.split(" ")`, then check what words contain "\n"

```
for(String s : string.split(" ")) {
    if(s.contains("\n"))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Both `line` and `And` in my sentence contain `\n`. But, if I were to check if the word either started with `\n` or ended with it, it gives me no results.

```
if(s.contains("\n")) {
    System.out.println("Contains");

    if(s.startsWith("\n"))
        System.out.println("Starts with");
    else if(s.endsWith("\n")) {
        System.out.println("Ends with");
    else
        System.out.println("Does not contain");
}
```

My result from that:

```
Contains
Does not contain
```

So, if the word contains a `\n`, but it doesn't start or end with it, where exactly is it and how can I manage it without using `replaceAll(String, String)`?

Comment: I guess new line might be represented as `\r\n` on your system (Windows).

Comment: @Crozin in that case `'\n'` would still be the last character...

Comment: `\n` is in the whitespace class, so is " ". Split on `\s+` to get all those nasty unseen separator delimiters. Don't rely on Split() default BS, never rely if it is to be semi-portable.

Comment: Diagnostic prints where spaces and newlines are important should have bracketing or quoting characters. Eg 'print("<"+theString+">")'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What happens is that the string looks like:

```
"This is the first line\nAnd this is the second"
```

So when you split it by `" "` you get:

```
"line\nAnd"
```

When you print it, it looks like two separate strings.To demonstrate this, try adding an extra print in the `for` loop:

```
for (final String s : string.split(" ")) {
    if (s.contains("\n")) {
        System.out.print(s);
        System.out.println(" END");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
line
And END
```

---

And when you try to check whether a string starts or ends with `"\n"` you won't get any result because in fact the string `"line\nAnd"` doesn't start or end with `"\n"`

Comment: `\n` is a whitespace! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Comment: Not English native speaker, what's the correct name of `" "`?

Comment: @MariuszS I think you meant to link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(computer_science) in your first comment. :) You linked to an article about a programming language called Whitespace, not to an article explaining the concept of whitespace chars.

Answer (score 5):

It is here `"line\nAnd"`

When you print this, it comes out as

```
line
And
```

Comment: so you're saying 'line' and 'And' is seen as one word, connected by \n?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Sure. You split on space, so the \n is unaffected.

Comment: @VinceEmigh If you want to split words, you should use `string.split("\\s+")`.

Comment: @Njol what affect would that regex have? Also, I've seen another one, \\w and \\w+, mind telling me the differences between the 3?

Comment: @VinceEmigh See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). `\\s+` matches one ore more whitespace characters, while `\\W+` matches one or more non-word characters, e.g. numbers and symbols as well as whitespace. `\\S` and `\\W` are the respective negations of the other two.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **line** and **And**. It's **line\nAnd**. You have seen in console:

**line** 
**And**

exactly because of the line break character **\n**.

So its; in the middle and if you change the code to `s.contains("\n"))`. You will see it.

Answer (score 2):

String :

```
This is the first line\nAnd this is the second
```

After splitting with `" " (space)` you will get output as : `line\nAnd`, so it means string does not start with or end with `\n`.

```
if (s.contains("\n")) {
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Output:

```
line
And
```